# Printing a string in println

Tags: java, jgrasp

Hello This is what I am working with right now

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DialogViewer2  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
       System.out.println(name);
   }
}
```

How Would I Get this to display `"Hello,name!"` with it using the name you typed it?

Comment: `System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
System.out.println("\"Hello, " + name + "!\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an information dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame, "Hello, " + name + "!", "Hello", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```